# How do I keep a marker in the center of the screen while user is scrolling the map ? Android

Tags: android

Android: I need to keep a marker (static) in the center of the screen while you scroll in google map and to retrieve the location of the marker.someone can give me an idea?

Comment: I believe you have to keep track of that location; like the answer below suggested using camera position

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the marker in a different view on top of the map so that it doesn't move when you drag the map and use this to get the center of the map:

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().target
```